# mat-autocomplete panel opening on form load in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-autocomplete

The first autocomplete control's selection panel is opened when I open modal dialog and I am trying to close the panel as shown below:

html:

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input
    #autoCompleteInput
    matInput
    type="text"
    [matAutocomplete]="auto"
  >
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" autoActiveFirstOption="true" [displayWith]="displayFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
      {{option.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

ts:

```js
//@ViewChild('autoCompleteInput', { read: MatAutocompleteTrigger }) autoComplete: MatAutocompleteTrigger; 
// I also tried this
@ViewChild(MatAutocompleteTrigger) autoCompleteInput: MatAutocompleteTrigger;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  debugger;
  this.autoCompleteInput.closePanel();
}
```

But unfortunately the first autocomplete's panel is opened on dialog load. How can I prevent the panel opened or if it is not possible, close the panel?

Comment: How autocomplete is get opened while modal open?

Comment: Modal is opened, after afterviewinit is executed,

Comment: Are you opening autocmplete manually?

Comment: Not actually, instead I make focus on the first element when opening dialog. For this reason, when a mant-autocomplete is the first control on the dialog then its panel list opened as it is focused. At this step I am trying to close panel or prevent it to be closed or prevent that control to be focused. There is also a property lsomething ike `panelOpen` and I set it to false. But it does not make any sense.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Answer (score 1):

just give

```
autoFocus:false 

this.dialog.open(yourcomponent,{
autoFocus:false
});
```